# How can I combine two lists in Nix?

Tags: nix, nixos

I've currently got a list defined as:

```
   environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     acpi
     ag
     alacritty
     audacity
     awscli
     bash
     breeze-gtk
     cabal-install
    ];
```

How would I go about defining two lists and then merging them to set the `environment.systemPackages` value?

I'd like to split the list so it's easier to manage groups of related packages.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/language-operators.html

The `++` operator:

```
nix-repl> [1 2 3]  ++ [5 6]
[ 1 2 3 5 6 ]
```

Code example:

```
let
  unstable = import <unstable> {
    config = config.nixpkgs.config; 
  };
  examplePkgs = with pkgs; [
    bash
  ];
in
{

   environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
     google-chrome
   ]
   ++ examplePkgs;
```

Comment: The link is outdated. New link: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/language-operators.html

Comment: [lib.lists.unique](https://ryantm.github.io/nixpkgs/functions/library/lists/#function-library-lib.lists.unique) can be useful here